# lightning-tabset tab styling hooks don't work

Tags: slds, slds-styling-hooks

Say I have a simple tabset:

```
<lightning-tabset variant="vertical" active-tab-value={activeTabValue} class="tab-active">
        <lightning-tab label="Dashboard" value="dashboard" onactive={handleActive}>
           foo
        </lightning-tab>
</lightning-tabset>
```

My CSS file:

```
.tab-active {
    --sds-c-tabs-item-color-border-active: #545164;
    --sds-c-tabs-item-color-border-hover: #545164;
    --sds-c-tabs-item-text-color: #545164;
    --sds-c-tabs-item-text-color-active: #545164;
    --sds-c-tabs-list-color-border: #545164;
}
```

Does not do anything...

However I was able to drill down into built-in hooks:

```
.tab-active {
    --lwc-colorBackground: #545164;
    --lwc-colorBackgroundAlt: #545164;
    --lwc-colorBackgroundPathIncompleteHover: #545164;
    --lwc-colorBorder: #545164;
    --lwc-colorTextActionLabel: white;
    --lwc-brandTextLink: white;
}
```

This works ok for tab labels, but also applies style for the rest of application.

I've tried to use something like `.tab-active lightning-tab-bar {` but that doesn't apply style anywhere.

Comment: Seems like based on component variant, its is rendering different SLDS markup: [tabs](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tabs/), [vertical](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/vertical-tabs/) and [scoped](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/scoped-tabs/). Its frustrating that the hooks are missing from the variant [vertical](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/vertical-tabs/) and very little info on [scoped](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/scoped-tabs/), hooks is only properly mentioned for tabs.

Comment: Yeah absolutely that was my conclusion too. Now I'm on a mission to style using lwc hooks, which I am not sure is kosher at all.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it with this css hack

```
renderedCallback() {
        const style = document.createElement('style');
        style.innerText = `
            lightning-tabset.tab-active > div > lightning-tab-bar {
                --uiBgColor: #d9253e;
                --uiBgColorHover: #a41c2f;
                --backgroundColor: #33313D;
                --backgroundColorActive: #6e6d74;
            
                --lwc-colorBackground: var(--backgroundColor);
                --lwc-colorBackgroundAlt: var(--backgroundColorActive);
                --lwc-colorBackgroundPathIncompleteHover: var(--uiBgColorHover);
                --lwc-colorTextActionLabelActive: white;
                --lwc-colorBorder: var(--backgroundColor);
                --lwc-colorTextActionLabel: white;
                --lwc-brandTextLinkActive: white;
                --lwc-brandTextLink: white;
                --lwc-colorTextIconDefault: white;
            }
        `;
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-tabset').appendChild(style);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The *vertical* variant of [`lightning-tabset`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tabset) internally renders the HTML of SLDS [Vertical Tabs](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/vertical-tabs/). And the SLDS [Vertical Tabs](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/vertical-tabs/) blueprint unfortunately doesn't have a hooks section yet which is a bummer.

Also if I read the code correctly, comparing the styles in between [tabs](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/blob/main/ui/components/tabs/base/_index.scss#L78) and [vertical tabs](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/blob/main/ui/components/vertical-tabs/base/_index.scss#L117) of [design token](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system) CSS code in github, seems like the styling hooks are not added to vertical tabs yet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is the exact solution:

```
renderedCallback() {
if(this.template.querySelector('lightning-tabset')){
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerText = `
        .custom-tab .slds-tabs_default__item.slds-is-active:after{
            background-color: #E42525;
        }
        .custom-tab .slds-tabs_default__item:hover:after{
            background-color: #E42525;
        }
        .custom-tab .slds-tabs_default__link{
            color: black;
        }
    `;
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-tabset').appendChild(style);
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

Please use this
:root{
--sds-c-tabs-item-color-border-active: #545164;
--sds-c-tabs-item-color-border-hover: #545164;
--sds-c-tabs-item-text-color: #545164;
--sds-c-tabs-item-text-color-active: #545164;
--sds-c-tabs-list-color-border: #545164;
}

Comment: Why does this work? How is it different from the existing answers? "Code dumps" aren't useful answers. The explanation is as important as the solution itself.